CameraX is recomposing and making the screen glitch when text is updated
I have a camera screen in Jetpack Compose. It has another ImageView(SubcomposeAsyncImage) that gets updated with the image count when I take an image.
Issue:

The camera preview is not opening completely (look at the bottom, black portion before clicking the image. When i click an image it gets to full screen.
Whenever the SubcomposeAsyncImage is updated, the camera preview recomposes and
glitches the screen.

Here is the code:
CameraScreen:
@Composable
fun CamScreen(
    navController: NavController, viewModel: CamViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    CameraContent(
        onTakePhoto = viewModel::onTakePhoto,
        stackUrl = viewModel.state.value.stackUrl,
        stackCount = viewModel.state.value.stackCount ?: 0
    )
}


@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun CameraContent(
    onTakePhoto: (File) -> Unit,
    stackUrl: String,
    stackCount: Int
) {
    // Camera permission state
    val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    )

    if (cameraPermissionState.status.isGranted) {
        CameraScreenPreview(
            onPhotoSaved = onTakePhoto,
            stackUrl = stackUrl,
            stackCount = stackCount
        )
    } else {
        CameraPermission(cameraPermissionState)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun CameraPermission(cameraPermissionState: PermissionState) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
            .background(Color.White),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        val textToShow = if (cameraPermissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) {
            // If the user has denied the permission but the rationale can be shown,
            // then gently explain why the app requires this permission
            stringResource(id = R.string.camera_permission_rationale)
        } else {
            // If it's the first time the user lands on this feature, or the user
            // doesn't want to be asked again for this permission, explain that the
            // permission is required
            stringResource(id = R.string.camera_permission_required)
        }
        Text(textToShow, color = Black)
        Button(
            onClick = { cameraPermissionState.launchPermissionRequest() },
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .padding(top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Text("Request permission")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CameraScreenPreview(
    onPhotoSaved: (File) -> Unit,
    stackUrl: String,
    stackCount: Int
) {
    val haptic = LocalHapticFeedback.current
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val controller = remember {
        LifecycleCameraController(context).apply {
            setEnabledUseCases(
                CameraController.IMAGE_CAPTURE
            )
        }
    }

    Scaffold { padding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(padding)
        ) {
            CameraPreview(controller)

            if (stackUrl.isNotEmpty()) {
                Stack(
                    url = stackUrl,
                    stackCount = stackCount,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.BottomStart)
                )
            }

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround
            ) {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    haptic.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackType.LongPress)
                    takePhoto(controller, context, onPhotoSaved) {}
                }, modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp)) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.camera),
                        contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.take_photo),
                        tint = Color.Unspecified
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CameraPreview(
    controller: LifecycleCameraController
) {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    AndroidView(
        factory = {
            PreviewView(it).apply {
                this.controller = controller
                controller.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner)
            }
        }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
}


private fun takePhoto(
    controller: LifecycleCameraController,
    context: Context,
    onPhotoSaved: (File) -> Unit,
    onError: (ImageCaptureException) -> Unit
) {
    val outputDirectory = AppUtils.getOutputDirectory(activityContext = context as Activity)
    val photoFile = File(
        outputDirectory, "s_receipt_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg"
    )

    val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

    controller.takePicture(outputOptions,
        ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
        object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
            override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                onPhotoSaved(photoFile)
            }

            override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                onError(exception)
                Timber.tag("Camera").e("Photo capture failed: ${exception.message}", exception)
            }
        })
}

@Composable
fun Stack(url: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier, stackCount: Int) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.size(50.dp)
    ) {
        if (url.isNotEmpty()) {
            StackItem(url)
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp), color = LightBlue
                )
                .padding(
                    start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 2.dp, bottom = 2.dp
                )
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = stackCount.toString(),
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                lineHeight = 16.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight(600),
                color = Color.White,
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun StackItem(url: String, degree: Float = 0f) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val uri = Uri.parse(url)
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .rotate(degree)
            .size(45.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = 2.dp
        ),
    ) {
        if (contentResolver.getType(uri)?.contains("pdf") == true || url.contains("pdf")) {
            val pdfState = rememberVerticalPdfReaderState(
                resource = ResourceType.Local(Uri.parse(url)), isZoomEnable = false
            )
            VerticalPDFReader(state = pdfState,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(45.dp)
                    .background(color = Color.Gray)
                    .pointerInteropFilter {
                        when (it.action) {
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {

                            }

                            else -> {}
                        }
                        true
                    }

            )
        } else {
            SubcomposeAsyncImage(
                model = url,
                contentDescription = "receipt",
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(45.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
                    .clickable {

                    },
                loading = {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        color = Navy, modifier = Modifier.background(Transparent)
                    )
                },
            )
        }
    }
}

ViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
open class CamViewModel @Inject constructor(
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf(CamState())
    val state: State<CamState> = _state

    private val _docs = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(immutableListOf())
    val docs = _docs.asStateFlow()

    fun onTakePhoto(file: File) {
        val newDocs = ArrayList(docs.value)
        newDocs.add(file.path)
        _docs.value = newDocs
        _state.value = state.value.copy(stackUrl = file.path, stackCount = newDocs.size)
    }
}

camera liberary:
cameraxVersion = "1.3.4"
implementation(libs.androidx.camera.core)
implementation(libs.androidx.camera.camera2)
implementation(libs.androidx.camera.view)
implementation(libs.androidx.camera.lifecycle)

Screen recording of the issue: https://imgur.com/a/UBjtlhC
